# How can I use scala sources from a different location in a sbt project and also make it work with IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

This project compiles and runs fine using sbt.
https://github.com/stuhajbejovic/multi-project-sbt

The problem I'm having is when I open the hello.sbt project in intellij idea, it says:

```
cannot resolve symbol testing
```

when I hover over the red import statement on line 1 of `hello.scala`.

I also tried using this in my build.sbt:

```
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile += baseDirectory.value / "../common"
```

but then I get the following warning in IntelliJ and can't run the app inside IntelliJ:

These source roots cannot be included in the IDEA project model.

Solution: declare an SBT project for these sources and include the project in dependencies.

Is there a way to get IntelliJ to follow sbt configuration to where the common sources are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a multi-project *SBT* build file. That is, have one `build.sbt` file for the entire project. *IntelliJ* should honor that without a problem.

I think your `build.sbt` file, which should go in your project's root directory, would need to look like this:

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  scalaVersion := "2.12.1",
  version := "0.1"
)

lazy val common = project.in(file("sbt_testing/common")).
settings(commonSettings: _*).
settings(
  name := "common"
)

lazy val hello = project.in(file("sbt_testing/hello")).
dependsOn(common).
settings(commonSettings: _*).
settings(
  name := "Hello"
)
```

As you can see, you can group settings common to both projects and also ensure better consistency between them.

You will need to remove the `build.sbt` files in `sbt_testing/common` and `sbt_testing/hello`.

**UPDATE**: Corrected use of `commonSettings` in the *SBT* `build.sbt` file. Apologies for the confusion!

**UPDATE 2**: In order to run the code in the `HelloWorld` class, you will need to do the following (I also renamed the "root" project to "hello"):

```
$ sbt
[info] Loading global plugins from /home/user/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /home/user/src/multiSbt/project
[info] Set current project to multisbt (in build file:/home/user/src/multiSbt/)
> project hello
[info] Set current project to Hello (in build file:/home/user/src/multiSbt/)
> run
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to 
/home/user/src/multiSbt/sbt_testing/hello/target/scala-2.12/classes...
[info] Running HelloWorld 
Hello, world!
This is from common: testing 123
[success] Total time: 3 s, completed May 1, 2017 3:27:16 PM
```

For more information on *SBT* multi-project builds, refer to the [official documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Multi-Project.html)...

Comment: I tried the example you provided but I get the following errors when running sbt in my project's root directory:

$ sbt
Loading /usr/share/sbt/bin/sbt-launch-lib.bash
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
/home/st/sbt_testing/build.sbt:7: error: overloaded method value settings with alternatives:
  (ss: sbt.Def.Setting[_]*)sbt.Project <and>
  => Seq[sbt.Def.Setting[_]]
 cannot be applied to (Seq[sbt.Def.Setting[String]])
settings(commonSettings).
^
/home/st/sbt_testing/build.sbt:14: error: overloaded method value sett

Comment: Whoops. You're correct. I'll correct the code in a moment. Sorry for the confusion...

Comment: $ sbt
Loading /usr/share/sbt/bin/sbt-launch-lib.bash
[info] Set current project to sbt_testing (in build file:/home/st/sbt_testing/)
> project hello
[info] Set current project to Hello (in build file:/home/st/sbt_testing/)
> run
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.14.1 ...
[info] Done updating.
java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected.
 at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last hello/compile:run for the full output.
[error] (hello/compile:run) No main class detected.
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed May 1, 2017 5:19:00 PM

Comment: See Update 2 in my answer.

Comment: I am able to compile but can't run it. Which directory is your build.sbt in?

Comment: Is the GitHub project yours? If so, I'll send you a Pull Request that will work...

Comment: I just sent the PR over. It works for me. Having to switch to the `hello` project before using the `run` command is a little artificial. There are _SBT_ plugins (such as `sbt-release` or `sbt-assembly`) that you can use to create an executable `jar` file. Raise another _StackOverflow_ question if you need help with that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143132/discussion-between-mike-allen-and-wawrzyniec-pruski).

Comment: It worked, my build.sbt was in the wrong location. Once I moved it outside the sbt_testing folder it started working. I also tried keeping build.sbt inside sbt_testing folder and removed sbt_testing/ from the project. line in build.sbt and that also worked fine. Thanks for all the help. One more question I have is how to specify multiple libraryDependencies in that build.sbt for the hello project?

Comment: I'll do another PR containing some library dependency examples. Glad everything is working for you!